# How to sort NSArray of objects depending on an NSNumber field in it?

Tags: sorting, ios7, nsarray, foursquare, nssortdescriptor

I have an NSArray of Foursquare places but it is not sorted by distance.So How can i sort my NSArray depending on a distance item in it.

```
      for(int i = 0 ; i <self.nearbyVenues.count ; i++)
                                          {

          FSVenue * venue = [self.nearbyVenues objectAtIndex:i];
           NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",venue.location.distance ]ascending:YES
   selector:@selector(compare:)];
         [self.nearbyVenues sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

                                          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sorting the array N times. This is what you need.

```
[self.nearbyVenues sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"location.distance" ascending:YES]]];
```